# Can shutdown() be used for clean up operations in Android content provider?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

Can shutdown() be used for clean up operations in Android content provider? Is shutdown() called automatically when activity is destroyed or does it have to be invoked manually & for testing purposes only? Is it a bad practice to invoke it in production code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are referring to [`shutdown()` on `ContentProvider`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProvider.html#shutdown%28%29), it is never called, unless you call it. Moreover, you should really only call it in unit testing. After all, your `ContentProvider` may well be used by your app otherwise, `shutdown()` or not.

Comment: Yes, that is what I was referring to. Other than shutdown(), what other alternatives do we have for performing clean up activities?

Comment: @ankesh: If your `ContentProvider` needs "clean up activities", either get rid of the `ContentProvider` or get rid of the "clean up activities". Your process can be terminated at any time for any reason. No "clean up activities" anywhere in your app are necessarily invoked. And, since a `ContentProvider` runs as long as your process does, it needs to be usable right up until the moment the process is terminated.